# To store web data crawled by nutch into hdfs

Tags: integration, hadoop2, nutch

I have installed hadoop 2.x and nutch 1.x. can anyone guide me how to store nutch webcrawled data into hdfs? Like providing any documentation or any link regarding that configuration.
Thank you all.

Comment: my hadoop version is 2.7.5 and nutch version is 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Nutch is designed to store data on HDFS. Assumed that Hadoop is running and the `hadoop` command is on $PATH you need to

1. modify the configuration (conf/nutch-site.xml etc.) and (re)compile Nutch by running `ant runtime`
2. call the scripts (`crawl` or `nutch`) in `runtime/deploy/bin`, e.g.
   `.../runtime/deploy/bin/crawl -s hdfs:///myseeds/ hdfs://.../crawl/ 3`

All crawled data will be stored on HDFS. If you do not have a Hadoop cluster running, you could start with a single-node cluster, see [NutchHadoopSingleNodeTutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopSingleNodeTutorial) and [nutch-test-single-node-cluster](https://github.com/sebastian-nagel/nutch-test-single-node-cluster).

Comment: yeah i started the same procedure in the links you have mentioned. but during ant runtime, it is pausing in the middle without any change. can you help with that? how long ant runtime will take time?

Comment: yeah i have installed. now when i am giving command like "hadoop jar apache-nutch-1.14.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5"

Comment: i am getting error- "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)" please help me with that.

Comment: Please run `bin/crawl`. The class crawl.Crawl has been replaced by the shell script in 2012 ([NUTCH-1087](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1087)).